# how to get grails class name from a string

Tags: grails

Here is a stripped down version of my grails domain objects:

```
//this is a lookup table
class PetType {
  String description
}

class Family {
   static hasMany = [
      petTypePreferred:PetType
   ]
}
```

In my controller I'm getting returned back from my gsp a parameter string value of 'petTypePreferred'.  Knowing that string value, and knowing the Domain class Family, how can I determine the Domain class from the 'petTypePreferred' string value?  In grails 2.2.4 the getPropertyByName(String value) method isn't seen as valid on a domain object, even though it's in the javadoc.

So I have String petTypePreferred, and Class Family, but I need to find Class PetType given those 2 pieces of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you want:

**Getting the domain class name**:

`hasMany` is a simple static `Map` in `Family`. The `Map` stores the field name as key and the target type as value. So you can get the domain class `PetType` from the string `petTypePreferred` using:

```
Familiy.hasMany['petTypePreferred']
```

**Getting the value of `description` inside `PetType` for a given `Family` instance:**

A Family can have multiple pet types (`hasMany`), so the result has to be a collection:

```
Family family = ...
List descriptions = family['petTypePreferred']*.description
```

This gives you the list of `PetType` descriptions for a `Family` instance named `family`.

Comment: Excellent.  Familiy.hasMany['petTypePreferred'] worked perfectly.  What exactly does that hasMany call do?  I've seen it in the domain declaration for relationship fields, but not used like this.

Comment: `hasMany` is used in domain classes to define gorm associations, see this for more details: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#gormAssociation